# Detecting last column in sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use the Lastcolumn from Sheet D in a formula in Sheet M. This is the code I have: `D!R[8]C " & LastColumn1 &` .

But it looks like the code is using the last column number in sheet M.

Can you please check what is wrong with this code?

```
Sub misc()
  Dim LastColumn1 As Long
  LastColumn1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("D").Range("a12").End(xlToRight).Column
End Sub
Sub try()
    Sheet1.Select        
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Offset(-2, 1).Value = counter & "Qtr"
    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
        ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=IFERROR(D!R[8]C " & LastColumn1 & " *(1+INDEX(A!R3C4:R418C27,MATCH(M!R2C,A!R2C4:R2C27,0))),0)"
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: what is the value of counter variable

Comment: The variable `LastColumn1` is set at module or global scope? When running the `Try` sub, what is the value of `LastColumn1` variable? Hover over it in break mode (step into the code), or debug it in another way, please.

Comment: Even when I put Option Explicit it is not working.
Option Explicit 
Sub try()
Dim LastColumn1 As Long
LastColumn1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("D").Range("A12").End(xlToRight).Value

Sheet1.Select

        Range("A4").Select
        ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Offset(-2, 1).Value = "Qtr"
        Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
        ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=IFERROR(D!R[8]C "LastColumn1" *(1+INDEX(A!R3C4:R418C27,MATCH(M!R2C,A!R2C4:R2C27,0))),0)"
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop
        End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You need a function for this.

```
Function LastColumn() as long
  LastColumn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("D").Range("a12").End(xlToRight).Column
end function
```

And then you call that function directly from your code:

```
Sub try()
    Sheet1.Select        
    Range("A4").Select
    lastCol = LastColumn '## Calling the function from above
    ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Offset(-2, 1).Value = counter & "Qtr"
    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
        ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=IFERROR(D!R[8]C " & lastCol & " *(1+INDEX(A!R3C4:R418C27,MATCH(M!R2C,A!R2C4:R2C27,0))),0)"
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can you please check what is wrong with this code?

You have an undeclared/uninitialized variable called `LastColumn1` which you are using in a formula string.  This variable has no value at runtime, which causes the error.

How to resolve it:

If you had simply used `Option Explicit`, you would be informed of a compilation error. `LastColumn1` variable is undeclared within the scope of the `try()` procedure.

Since you are not using `Option Explicit` (which requires that all variables be declared), the compiler initializes undeclared variables as type Variant, with an empty/0/null-string value.

So, what you have essentially is an obvious error with:

```
ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Formula = _
    "=IFERROR(D!R[8]C " & EMPTY & " * _
    (1+INDEX(A!R3C4:R418C27,MATCH(M!R2C,A!R2C4:R2C27,0))),0)"
```

Because the result of that concatenation is: `D!R[8]C` and that is an invalid Range (without a column index), it is undefined/cannot exist as such.

Using @iDevelop's function above will *probably* suffice for most ordinary, simple cases, however you may want to review the more robust methods described here:

[Error in finding last used cell in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920)